# jQuery Quote Issue with Function in OnClick

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's my code:

```
jQuery("#"+code+"_2").after("<a href='#' id='"+code+"_3' onclick='addfunction('"+code+"', event); return true;'><img src='special.gif' border='0'></a>");
```

I'm getting a syntax error on addfunction(. The code is a string and I tried wrapping it in quote, but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

UPDATE --- This works, but doesn't pass the code and event over in the function.

```
function addfunction() {
alert("THIS WORKS");
}
var myAnchor = $('<a href="#" id="' + code + '_3"><img src="special.gif" border="0"></a>').bind('click', addfunction);
$('#' + code + '_2').after(myAnchor);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works! Try to avoid the onclick event, use on() instead.

Create the anchor first, bind the click event to it, then append to DOM.

```
function addfunction(code, event) {
    alert("THIS WORKS, the code is: " + code);
}
var myAnchor = $('<a href="#" id="' + code + '_3"><img src="special.gif" border="0"></a>').bind('click', function(event) {
    addfunction(code, event);
});
$('#' + code + '_2').after(myAnchor);
```

Comment: Hey this works, but it doesn't look like it's passing the code and event in the function.

Comment: I've updated my example, now including code and event as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the inner single quote:

```
jQuery("#"+code+"_2").after("<a href='#' id='"+code+"_3' onclick='addfunction(\'"+code+"\', event); return true;'><img src='special.gif' border='0'></a>");
```

Comment: I did exactly that and it still throws a syntax error addunction( on click.

Comment: addfunction(
------------^

Comment: What's the generated HTML of this anchor tag?  I mean after jQuery inserts it into the page?

Comment: If I take the quotes out, I get this error: SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal / addfunction(03558WH40, event); return true;

Answer (score 1):

For the sanity of your mind try to reorganize your code:

```
var insertLink = function(code) {
   var parent = jQuery('#' + code + '_2');
   var a = $('<a/>', {
       href: '#',
       id: code + '_3'
   }).html('<img src='special.gif' border='0'>').on('click', function() {
      addfunction(code, event);
      return true;
   });
}
```

I haven't tested the code, but you got the point.

Answer (score 0):

you're problem is here `addfunction('"+code+"', event)`  you need to escape the single quotes within the onnClick value

```
jQuery("#"+code+"_2").after("<a href='#' id='"+code+"_3' onclick='addfunction(\'"+code+"\', event); return true;'><img src='special.gif' border='0'></a>");
```